# Как поставить 3 маркера на maps iframe?

Tags: яндекс-карты

Можно ли поставить 3 маркера на карту которую получаю через iframe ( Конструктор карт), а НЕ через API JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно, порядок действий идентичный. Расставить метки, "получить код карты" - "iframe".

Выглядеть будет [так](https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/?um=constructor%3Ac4e8fab06a51bc6599db4da3586d7dca0a884e85638865fed243c32381f2191b&source=constructor%22%20width=%22500%22%20height=%22400%22%20frameborder=%220%22).
Kод для iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/?um=constructor%3Ac4e8fab06a51bc6599db4da3586d7dca0a884e85638865fed243c32381f2191b&amp;source=constructor" width="500" height="400" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```